# Encoded params in Zend Framework 2 route

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm having issues setting up the route parameters for my ZF2 project. I want to be able to pass a URL as a parameter to the page, but each attempt to do so results in a 404.

I have created a URL module and would like to set it up so that the following controller passes in the URL as the id param. The controller extends the AbstractRestfulController class so the examples below would be using the get($id) method.

Controller address:

```
http://localhost/url/
```

With param:

```
http://localhost/url/http://www.google.co.uk
```

The router section of my module.config.php looks like the below:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'url' => array(
            'type' => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/url[/][:id]',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'URL\Controller\URL',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

If I have to pass the encode the parameter then it wouldn't be the end of the world, although I'd prefer not to.

With the param encoded:

```
http://localhost/url/http:%2F%2Fwww.google.co.uk
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't directly refer to your question, but i suggest you work up your routes a little bit! Currently your route would match way too much, even this:

```
http://localhost/url1
```

And i don't think you wanna work with this, here's my suggestion:

```
'type'    => 'segment',
'options' => array(
    'route'    => '/url[/[:id]]',
    'defaults' => array(
        'controller' => 'URL\Controller\URL',
    ),
    'constraints' => array(
        'id' => '<InsertURLRegexHere>'
    )
)
```

A little more related to your question: the ViewHelpers automatically urlencode the important characters, as can be seen in [`Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/Router/Http/Segment.php#L411), `encode()` is used within `buildPath()`.

Where exactly does your behavior occur and are you certain that it isn't just the browser to decode the url for view-purposes? Chrome loves to do this kinda thing ^^

Comment: Thanks Sam. I've now added the following constraint: 'constraints' => array('id' => '(https?:\/\/)?([\da-zA-Z\.-]+)\.([a-zA-Z\.]{2,6})([\/\w\.\?-]*)*\/?')

Comment: And it's working! I'm now able to pass http://www.google.com as part of the URL. Thank you.